# Why did Google leave html tag open?

Tags: html

In Google' s 404 page, html tag is used without a closing tag.
You can see the code yourself by navigating to www.googleusercontent.com
This doesn't generate any error on w3c validator. Why is that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><img src=//www.google.com/images/errors/logo_sm.gif alt=Google></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should help explain:

> According to Google’s latest guidelines to speed up the web, there are
>   a number of optional tags in HTML4 that you can omit to save speed,
>   even if it makes you feel a little queasy as a developer. (Google is
>   quick to point out these tricks are for HTML and not XHTML.)
>
> The Google homepage and search results pages don’t end their `<body>`
>   and `<html>` elements. They just leave them open– a lot like a lazy
>   developer might do and then feel guilty when he comes back and sees
>   the mistake.
>
> Only this “mistake” is really part of Google’s strategy of treating
>   their performance as a competitive advantage. All browsers work well
>   without the tags and the tags take up time, so they’re excited to
>   eliminate any millisecond they can for their visitors.

http://blog.errorhelp.com/2009/06/27/the-highest-traffic-site-in-the-world-doesnt-close-its-html-tags/

Answer (score 2):

[Both start and end tags are actually optional](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-html-element):

> In the HTML syntax only, both the start and end tags are optional, and so for convenience either may be omitted, unless you wish to specify attributes on this element, in which case, at least the start tag needs to be included.

Answer (score 0):

From the [HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/spec.html#html):

> An html element’s end tag may be omitted if the html element is not
>   immediately followed by a comment and the element contains a body
>   element that is either not empty or whose start tag has not been
>   omitted.